Another Butterfly theorem — Conway like circle

Have You seen these result as follows before?


In Figure 1: $AA'=BB'=tAB$; $CC'=DD'=tCD$, where t is real number then $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral iff $A'B'C'D'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.



In the Figure 2: $B_a, C_a, C_b, A_b, A_c, B_c$ lie on a conic.

See also:

Butterfly theorem
Conway circle theorem



Power of a point might be used to prove it.

Yes, proof is easy
